# Running a Junit test case from Ant build file - always a fail

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, junit, junit4

I have a file in my java project called HelloWorldServiceTest.java. Its under com.dummy.test under the src folder.

Below is a snippet of my Ant build.xml file

```
<target name="junit" depends="compile">
  <junit printsummary="yes">
   <classpath>
       <fileset dir="lib"/>
   </classpath>
   <batchtest fork="yes">
       <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="com/dummy/test/HelloWorldServiceTest.java/>
   </batchtest>

  </junit>
</target>
```

Output is always as follows:

```
junit:
    [junit] Running com.dummy.test.HelloWorldServiceTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed 0 sec
    [junit] Test com.dummy.test.HelloWorldServiceTest FAILED
```

Can anyone help me on this?

1. Manually running HelloWorldServiceTest generates no error and always a success. Running it through ant always shows FAILED and there is even no stack trace why it was failing.
2. lib is where the junit jar is placed

When I added junit -debug as arguments, I saw the ff.

```
Finding class com.dummy.test.HelloWorldServiceTest
Class java.lang.System loaded from parent loader (parentfirst)
[junit] Test com.dummy.test.HelloWorldServiceTest FAILED
```

and

```
<error message="com.dummy.test.HelloWorldServiceTest" type="java.lang.ClassNotFoundException />
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown source)
...
...
...
```

Seems it cant find HelloWorldServiceTest.class

Comment: Please try running ant with "-debug" flag. This will dump more information about classpath.  Also check the test result xml.  Provide the information as edit to uyour question.

Comment: Where should i set the "-debug" ?

Comment: "ant -debug <remaining normal command options>

Comment: I saw additional logs like "Class loaded from ..etc..etc" but I did see anything related about what it failed.

Comment: Jayan, I posted above, the errors that were shown.

Comment: Well, your own production and test classes are not in the classpath. Only the lib directory is in the classpath. Uou need to add the target directory of the compilation and test compilation tasks in the classpath too. Otherwise, Java can't load your own classes. I really recommend, ditching Ant, adopting the gradle/maven project layout and switching to gradle.

Comment: Try to set fork=true or/and basedir=${src.dir}